# Write a file on every submission or create custom export format?

Tags: webforms, importing-exporting

Is there a way of writing or outputting a file on every submission? For example, if a user submits a 'contact us' form, this will write a file to a database or disk.

The file I want to write per submission is an XML file, but will need the XML file to be based on a specific structure, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Exportfile>
<Header>
 <DocumentName>Contact us xml export - reference [webform_submission:sid]</DocumentName>
</Header>
    <Message>
<field1>[webform_submission:values:field_1]</field1>
<field2>[webform_submission:values:field_2]</field2>
    </Message>
</Exportfile>
```

Or, whether you can create some sort of custom export option within the **Results > Download** section? Essentially, to allow a backend user to export/download individual submissions as an XML file (based on a specific XML structure like above)

[image]

Comment: Once this patch gets committed you can create a Webform Attachment element (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7exQFDIHhQ) that generates an XML file, which can then be exported. @see https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3165998

It is also very easy to create a custom WebformExporter plugin

Comment: Thanks for this @jrockowitz, the video is really helpful and I think answers my query around generating a custom XML file via the Webform Attachment module. Does the patch essentially allow you to select the Webform Attachment element, so that an admin can download the results i.e. in my case, all the XML files

Additionally, I cannot seem to find a page to download and install the module but within the 'Extend' section in Drupal, I can see a module that is currently unticked called ' 
Webform Attachment'. I am guessing this is the 'Webform Attachment element' you mentioned?

Comment: The patch will allow your XML attachments to be exported. The Webform Attachment module is included in the core Webform module.